# proxy: no HTTP 0.9 request (with no host line)

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-proxy

I'm getting a bunch of these errors in my error.log:

[client 1.2.3.4] proxy:  no HTTP 0.9 request (with no host line) on incoming request and preserver hose set forcing hostname to be www.mydomain.com for uri /

My config is essentially:

```
ProxyRequests Off

<VirtualHost 1.2.3.4:80>
ServerName www.mydomain.com
DocumentRoot "c:/apache/htdocs"

ProxyPreserveHost On
ProxyPass / http://172.1.1.1/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 1.2.3.4:443>
ServerName www.mydomain.com
DocumentRoot "c:/apache/htdocs"
# SSL Stuff

ProxyPreserveHost On
ProxyPass / http://172.1.1.1/
</VirtualHost>
```

Anyone have an idea how to eliminate those warnings?

Comment: Is the client address your server?

Comment: No, sorry. I just tried to anonymize the ip's to protect the guilty.

Comment: Well, that warning just informs you that you have `ProxyPreserveHost` set and got a request with no `Host` header, so the server needed to improvise a header to send to the proxy backend.  You can ignore the error, especially because those `HTTP/0.9` clients are usually bots, not actual users.

Comment: OK.  Looks like you are right.  They are coming from a server iron and our monitoring servers.  Thanks!  Wanna post your answer as an answer and I'll mark it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These warnings are just making the effort to inform you that Apache has done something not-quite-alright (injecting a `Host` header in a request that didn't have one) in an effort to make sure the client can access the proxied content.

Since `ProxyPreserveHost On` is set, Apache presumes that the backend server won't be ok with having a `Host` header of `172.1.1.1`, nor does it really know how to speak HTTP/0.9 to the backend server.. so it's improvising a bit, in the hopes that it works correctly, but informing you of that.

Generally, these can be ignored, which can unfortunately add noise to your logs.  Additionally, it's extraordinarily rare that a request like this comes from a human's web browser (the exception being possibly some older proxies); more likely it's a bot of some sort.

Comment: Note that if the "bot" accessing your web server is your own Nagios monitoring system you may need to change your Nagios config to specify the hostname to use with a line like `check_command check_http!"--hostname=www.mydomain.com"` in your service definition, even if your host definition uses the name rather than IP.